# IE9 CSS3 Drop down menu, errors errors errors

Tags: php, html, css

Before I ask my continue please keep in mind that I am only just getting back into web development and it has been almost 8 years since I have used HTML daily.

I am currently creating a [website](http://www.agradedemo.com)

I am using the CSS3 Drop Down Menu, I tweaked it a little bit to suit (colours, widths etc)
Here is the CSS code:

```
    #cssmenu{ height:37px; display:block; padding:0; margin: 0;  border:1px solid; border-radius:5px; } 
#cssmenu > ul {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li {list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; float:left; display:block; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; padding:12px 20px; font:bold 13px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); } 
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a{border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{ content:''; position:absolute; border-right:1px solid; top:-1px; bottom:-1px; right:-2px; z-index:99; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after{top:0; bottom:0;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{ content:''; position:absolute; top:18px; right:6px; border:5px solid transparent; border-top:5px solid #fff; } 
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:19px;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a{ background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f; padding-bottom:13px; padding-top:13px; top:-1px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul, #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div{display:block;} 
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover{background:#3f3f3f; border-color:#3f3f3f;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div{ display:none; width:auto; position:absolute; top:38px; padding:10px 0; background:#3f3f3f; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; z-index:999; } 
#cssmenu ul li > ul{width:200px;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li{display:block; list-style:inside none; padding:0; margin:0; position:relative;} 
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a{ outline:none; display:block; position:relative; margin:0; padding:8px 20px; font:10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); } 


#cssmenu, #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover{ background:#333333; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #222222 100%); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#333333), color-stop(100%,#222222)); background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); background:linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%,#222222 100%); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=0 ); } 
#cssmenu{border-color:#000;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a{border-right:1px solid #000; color:#fff;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after{border-color:#444;} 
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover{background:#111;}
```

And here is the relevant header.php (I am using PHP includes) :

```
<div id='cssmenu'> <ul>    <li class='active '><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>    <li><a href='about.php'><span>About</span></a></li>    <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Services</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='resdemo.php'><span>Residential Demolition</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='comdemo.php'><span>Commercial Demolition</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='partdemo.php'><span>Partial Demolition</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='excavate.php'><span>Excavation and Bobcat Jobs</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='asbestos.php'><span>Asbestos Removal</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='bins.php'><span>Bin Hire</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='internal.php'><span>Internal Strip Outs</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='concrete.php'><span>Concrete and Pavement Removal</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='trees.php'><span>Vegetation and Tree Removal</span></a></li>
      </ul>    </li>    <li><a href='/gallery/index.php' target='new'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>    <li><a href='quote.php'><span>Free Quote</span></a></li>    <li><a href='contact.php'><span>Contact</span></a></li> </ul>    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this menu has been a common request lately. BTW I have tried using the online css validator tool but it didn't make a difference, just took away the menu gradients (visible in Chrome and Firefox only)

Thanks,
Angie.

Comment: Since you're comfortable with CSS selectors, I suggest you look into JQuery, it will simplify your coding a lot, and you could just find a Menu plugin instead of designing one yourself. 2nd google result: http://speckyboy.com/2010/12/01/15-super-simple-jquery-menu-and-navigation-plugins/

Comment: @Mr. Alien - I want my drop down menu customized to suit IE9, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Ozzy I had a look into JQuery but I have limited javascript experience and I haven't been able to find a simple tutorial to explain the JQuery drop down menu. I'll have a look at the website you listed.

Comment: it works with the code you've provided but its not working on your website, so you want to make it work or you want to modify and change colors and all?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g8WUA/) is a cross browser compatible horizontal nav menu (w/ drop down subnav).

It doesn't have gradients though. For cross browser gradients, have a look at [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

You can play w/ the gradients and then get the CSS and add it to your menu.

Comment: Hi Cynthia, I tried that jsfiddle.net just then and it still isn't sitting right in IE9 and it transferred the whole page alignment to the left of the page. I will look into the css3pie program, thanks!

Comment: Did you make sure to clear the very next div following the nav bar? Since the nav bar LI elements are floated left, you have to make sure that you add clear:both to the div class of the next section.

Comment: Also, it looks like you only grabbed the HTML. You also need to grab the CSS from the jsfiddle example as well otherwise it won't work.